# Joining multiple junction tables and grouping results in a JSON-formatted array

Tags: sql, json, database, sqlite

Say I have a table of people:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Mary |
|  3 | Jane |
+----+------+
```

And various tables for clothing of various types, e.g. a table of shoes

```
+----+----------+--------------------+---------+
| id |  brand   |        name        |  type   |
+----+----------+--------------------+---------+
|  1 | Converse | High tops          | sneaker |
|  2 | Clarks   | Tilden cap Oxfords | dress   |
|  3 | Nike     | Air Zoom           | running |
+----+----------+--------------------+---------+
```

And then for each clothing type, I have a junction table recording what items of that type each person owns:

```
+--------+---------+
| person |  shirt  |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       3 |
|      1 |       4 |
|      2 |       2 |
...
```

I need a query that compiles these tables into a return like so:

```
+----+------+--------------------+
| id | name |   clothing items   |
+----+------+--------------------+
|  1 | John | [JSON in a string] |
|  2 | Mary | [JSON in a string] |
|  3 | Jane | [JSON in a string] |
+----+------+--------------------+
```

Where the `[JSON in a string]` for each row should look like this:

```
[
   {"type":"shirt","id":3},
   {"type":"shirt","id":4},
   {"type":"pant","id":2},
   {"type":"shoe","id":5}
]
```

How do I go about constructing this query in SQLITE? If needed, it's easy for me to define my own custom aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT person, ('[' || GROUP_CONCAT(clothing,',') || ']') AS clothing
  FROM (SELECT person, json_object('type','shirt','id',shirts) AS clothing
    FROM junction_shirts
    UNION
    SELECT person, json_object('type','pant','id',pants) AS clothing
    FROM junction_pants
    UNION
    SELECT person, json_object('type','shoe','id',shoes) AS clothing
    FROM junction_shoes)
GROUP BY person)
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.clothing
FROM people p LEFT JOIN cte c
ON c.person = p.id;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e4bg6nvW) for demo

Answer (score 0):

You can get you result by using this query. I t first json object then groups them into an array from each user id and name array:

```
 select 
t1.id
    ,t1."name"
    ,json_agg(new_object)
    from
(
select 
    se.id
    ,se."name"
    ,json_build_object('type',sa.type,'id',sa.id) as  new_object
from junction_table as  ss
inner join  shoe_table as sa on ss.shirt = sa.id
inner join people_table as se on ss.person = se.id 
)t1
group by t1.id,t1."name";
```